# Doubt About Newton's Laws Of Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose an object **A** is in physical contact with another object **B**, and both are in Earth's gravitational field (assumed to be uniform).
If both objects accelerate upwards with respect to ground (always remaining in contact) the Force exerted by object A on B increases while the gravitational force on A doesn't. Why? I think the force exerted by object A on B is the gravitational force so both should increase. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Why should the force between A and B increase? If they are at equal distances from each other, the force will be the same at all times (assuming it's only gravity at play).

Comment: To get A to exert a force on B there must be some force greater than gravity acting on A as well.  I don't really understand the confusion.

Comment: Why would weight increase? You weigh the same, no matter how much force you apply on something else,  no?

Comment: According to F(net) = ma, Normal Reaction would be greater if net acceleration is upwards, but according to Newton's third law, Normal Reaction should equal Force exerted by A on B.

Comment: Are the bodies stacked on top of each other, or side by side? Also to accelerate upwards a force needs to apply. Is it applied on _A_ only, or on _A_ and _B_ the same?

Comment: Stacked on top of each other, Force is being applied on the lower body B.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to concretize this before answering -- Let me know if I get the scenario wrong.

Rocket ships (think Saturn V rocket or something) were made such that the bottom part would accelerate upward, and the command module, stacked on top of the bottom part, would go along for the ride for the first part of the launch. Lets call the rocket booster $B$, and the command module $A$.

First let's mentally draw a Free-Body diagram of the booster $B$ (I recommend you do this on paper). There is a small downward force due to gravity with a magnitude of $F_g = -m_Bg$ assuming up is positive, and there is a large upward rocket force $F_R$. There is also a downward force of $A$ pressing down on $B$. Students like to call this a "normal force." Let's call this $F_{AonB}$. We get:

(1) $\sum{F_B} = F_R - m_B g - F_{AonB} $

Let's mentally draw a Free-Body diagram of the command module $A$. There is once again a downward gravitational force, but this time, all that's left after that is the force of the booster section $B$ upward on the command module. (Again, people like to refer to this as a "normal force.") Let's call that $F_{BonA}$. Thus:

(2) $\sum{F_A} = - m_A g + F_{BonA}$

Now, by Newton's 3rd law, we know that the forces that $A$ and $B$ exert on each other must be equal: $F_{AonB} = -F_{BonA}$. That means we get:

(3) $\sum{F_A} = - m_A g + F_{AonB}$.

OK -- so now an astronaut sitting in the command module $A$ wants to make the module accelerate faster. In other words, he wants $\sum{F_A}$ to increase. To do this, he sends a signal to the boosters, so this increases $F_{BonA}$ as you said*, and that also increases the magnitude of $F_{AonB}$ by the exact same amount (again by Newton's 3rd). An increase in $F_{AonB}$ increases $\sum{F_{A}}$ by equation (3), even though the force due to gravity on the command module does not change at all.

*Why does this increase $F_{BonA}$? Well, remember that $\sum{F_A} = m_A a = -m_A g + F_{BonA}$. (remember the acceleration $a$ is the same for both modules). In other words, we can write $F_{BonA} = m_A(a+g)$. Since $g$ and $m_A$ are unchangeable, when the astronaut increases $a$ (by turning up the rocket boosters), $F_{BonA}$ automatically increases too.

The key fallacy here (one I see all the time) is the tendency that folks have to automatically see a "normal force," and set it to $mg$. DON'T DO THIS! I see way too many students miss points on exams for this reason! $F_{AonB} \neq m_A g$. Instead they together add as shown in (3). Thus an increase in one does not imply an increase in the other.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, but how does the increase in F,BonA happen? Is it due to increase in Fr?

Comment: Check the update I gave to my answer -- the part with the asterisk. Those contact forces automatically increase when acceleration increases.

Comment: Thanks, I think the acceleration increase due to increase in Fr right?

Answer (score 0):

Block A is stacked on top of block B and a force is applied to B to make both blocks move upwards.

At all times, the contact forces between A and B are equal and opposite. 
When there is no acceleration, this contact force is equal to the weight of A. This is because the resultant force on each block is zero. For block A, its weight acting downwards is balanced by the normal reaction on it (upwards) from block B.

The contact force is not always equal to the weight of the object on top. If A falls onto B, it can (for a short time) exert a force greater than its weight, during the collision. If such a collision takes place in space, then there is still a contact force but both blocks are weightless. The contact force is required to change the motion of block A - ie to accelerate block A.

When the blocks accelerate, there is a non-zero resultant force acting on each of A and B (Newton's 2nd Law). The gravitational force on A has not changed. The extra force on A has come from an increase in the contact force between A and B. This increase comes from the applied force acting on B, part of which is transmitted to A as an increase in the contact force acting on A.